# display sql resultset to grid or table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, gridview

I need to know how to display the result of a `select` query in a datagrid or GridView with VB.NET?

Consider `SELECT * FROM some_table`. I don't know what columns the table has. Is there a way to just output the result to a table, with a dataset for example?

How can this be done easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it

I created a DataSet and filled it

```
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(ds, strList)
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    dataGridView1.DataBind()
```

And displayed it with

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dataGridView1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using 2 components:

- SqlDataSource
- GridView

Find both those in your webpage's Design view toolbox. Double click each to have them show up on your webform.

Your SQLDataSource will ask your for "SELECT" command. Paste in any SELECT statement, and you can preview the results. Better yet, create a stored procedure in SQL Server, and use it instead of an ad-hoc SQL statement.

Your GridView will, by default, have `AutoGenerateColumns=True`. This will ensure that your resultset from your SQLDataSource will have the columns named exactly on the GridView.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This article has some guidance and instructions: [GridView control in ASP.NET](http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/asp-net-2-0/grid-view-control-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I used a DataSet instead!

Answer (score 2):

Use SQLDataSource control to begin with. Click on its Smart Task handle. It's pretty straightforward to configure. set your datagrid's datasource to SQLDataSourceControl via your datagrid's Smart Task handle. Fire up your site and you'll see the result in your datagrid control.